# Overwrite a file with Dropbox API v2 in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dropbox-api

I'm trying to overwrite a file on Dropbox with Python 3.4 but can't figure out how to do it.  If the file doesn't exist, `dbx.files_upload(data, '/file.py')` creates the file as expected.

But if the file exists, I want to overwrite it.  I've tried

```
dbx.files_upload(data, '/file.py', mode=WriteMode('overwrite'))
```

which gives

```
NameError: name 'WriteMode' is not defined
```

and I've tried

```
dbx.files_upload(data, '/iot_main.py', overwrite=True)
```

which gives

```
TypeError: files_upload() got an unexpected keyword argument 'overwrite'
```

I feel as if I'm missing something obvious but lots of Googling for an answer doesn't help...

Thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try this one, from [Dropbox SDK Example](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python/blob/master/example/updown.py#L182).

```
dbx.files_upload(data, '/file.py', mode=dropbox.files.WriteMode.overwrite)
```

Comment: For those seeking for the raw json input (to use in `shell`): `{"path": "/some/file", "mode": "overwrite"}`

Answer (score 7):

just add this in your file.

```
from dropbox.files import WriteMode
```